# Get Count from Another List Based on Two values

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-view, custom-list

I have a document library containing documents to be commented on and I have a list which holds all these comments including a field with the commenters name and another field with the name of the document.

I have a requirement that at the document library view I need to display how many comments this user has inputted for this particular document. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Different options depending on whether you are on SharePoint Online in Office 365 or which version of on-prem server.

Comment: currently on prem and soon moving to online

Answer (score 0):

You could use Look up column to display the count of comments.

In the list, create a lookup column which get information from document library title column for document name.

In the document library, create a lookup column which get information from list document name column (Count Related) as below:

[image]

Check the article for more information about the lookup (count related) column:

[How to create count related lookup column in SharePoint custom lists?](http://pawansatope.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-create-count-related-lookup.html)

Comment: I think this approach would work if I was looking for all comments inputted for the particular document. I'm looking for the count of comments for a particular document made by the currently logged in user. so technically two different filters and not just one